# Good framework, based in C# for a project with mostly CRUD needs and a little business logic

Tags: c#, framework

I really hope this is an okay kind of question to ask here. I know it doesn't belong on Overflow proper.

I have a new project that I need to rapid develop. It's going to be first and foremost a pretty GUI to allow for CRUD on a small set of Oracle tables. Now, I am not just trying to re-write SQL Developer or Toad. I need to have an interface to allow non-tech types edit the values mostly of lookup tables and the like. There WILL be business logic, meaning buttons that take you to forms and move data along in a work flow. But, I will write all that. Doesn't need to have configurable workflow.

I want .Net C# up to 4.5.2 is good. Fresh IIS to install, no strange auth rules, just internal AD domain stuff.

I most want the Web GUI to come pre done for me. Something that looks nice and gives me flexibility to modify but that I don't have to plumb every screen.

Does such a thing exist? I mostly need to allow these lookups to be added/updated and just a teansey bit of business logic to be done. I'll do all the DDL myself and I can handle the integrations and such.

Does this exist?